# Receiving spam mail from my own domain (postfix)

Tags: postfix

First of all : I know this subject is already treated in a few other topics. Unfortunally, nothing I could have read seems to work, so I'm looking for a new way of doing this.

I'm receiving a few times per day some spam mails which seems to come from my own domain (even more : from the e-mail address which is receiving the e-mails).

This is some informations :

Source of spam email (no-reply@calendridel.fr is my email address, vaeserveur.fr is the main server) :

```
Return-Path: <no-reply@calendridel.fr>
Delivered-To: no-reply@calendridel.fr
Received: from static.vnpt.vn (unknown [113.190.69.222])
    by vaeserveur.fr (Postfix) with ESMTP id 945F82880099
    for <no-reply@calendridel.fr>; Tue, 10 Apr 2018 12:56:11 +0200 (CEST)
Authentication-Results: vaeserveur.fr; dkim=none reason="no signature";
    dkim-adsp=discard (insecure policy); dkim-atps=neutral
Message-ID: <CE6EC615C066BD13B31BC81DBB60CE6E@RS6IKWLC1Q>
From: <no-reply@calendridel.fr>
To: <no-reply@calendridel.fr>
Subject: Olenka29
Date: 10 Apr 2018 23:33:06 +0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0020_01D3D0F5.0276B9FD"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 15.4.3508.1109
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V15.4.3508.1109
```

This is what happens on logs for this e-mail :

```
Apr 10 12:56:10 vaeserveur postfix/smtpd[21347]: warning: hostname static.vnpt.vn does not resolve to address 113.190.69.222
Apr 10 12:56:10 vaeserveur postfix/smtpd[21347]: connect from unknown[113.190.69.222]
Apr 10 12:56:11 vaeserveur postfix/smtpd[21347]: 945F82880099: client=unknown[113.190.69.222]
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur postfix/cleanup[21354]: 945F82880099: message-id=<CE6EC615C066BD13B31BC81DBB60CE6E@RS6IKWLC1Q>
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur opendkim[29715]: 945F82880099: [113.190.69.222] [113.190.69.222] not internal
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur opendkim[29715]: 945F82880099: not authenticated
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur postfix/qmgr[17806]: 945F82880099: from=<no-reply@calendridel.fr>, size=1360, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur dovecot: lda(no-reply@calendridel.fr): msgid=<CE6EC615C066BD13B31BC81DBB60CE6E@RS6IKWLC1Q>: saved mail to INBOX
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur postfix/pipe[21356]: 945F82880099: to=<no-reply@calendridel.fr>, relay=dovecot, delay=1.1, delays=1/0/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur postfix/qmgr[17806]: 945F82880099: removed
Apr 10 12:56:12 vaeserveur postfix/smtpd[21347]: disconnect from unknown[113.190.69.222]
```

After the first e-mails received, I edited my DNS to make SPF and DKIM "stricts" as I could have seen in other topics (example with calendridel.fr but the same thing is done with vaeserveur.fr / i have my ip4 in the "a" record) :

```
calendridel.fr.                 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip6:2001:41d0:1:e7c2::1 -all"
_domainkey.calendridel.fr.      IN TXT "t=y; o=-;"
mail._domainkey.calendridel.fr. IN TXT ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa;" "[mykey]")
_adsp._domainkey.calendridel.fr. IN TXT "dkim=discardable"
_dmarc.calendridel.fr.          IN TXT ("v=DMARC1;p=none;adkim=r;aspf=r;sp=none;rua=mailto:contact@calendridel.fr;ruf=mailto:contact@calendridel.fr;")
```

Those changes were inefficient, so I edited postfix too : I added those line to `postfix/main.cf`:

```
#Helo Restrictions
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname

#Sender Restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access

#Recipient Restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unlisted_recipient, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

In the `postfix/access/sender_access` file, I tried to add calendridel.fr as a domain to reject (btw, doing so, is it supposed to block every email from the domain ? Meaning i wouldn't be able to send a e-mail from it myself ?) :

```
#Address            #Action
calendridel.fr      REJECT
```

This last change is recent (just after the last e-mail i received), but I guess it won't be enough.

If you have any clue, if you need more informations : let me know, I will give you with pleasure. (And sorry if my english is bad, as you can see I'm a frog... i mean, french !)

Comment: dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/905591/receiving-spam-from-my-own-email-address-postfix

Answer (score 1):

The [`check_sender_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) solution is correct and well suitable. Because it's a `hash:`, remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/access/sender_access` after any changes.

You are mistaken that this will reject all mail from this domain; only if it's used from an unauthorized origin. That's because you have two crucial tests before your `check_sender_access`:

- `permit_mynetworks` for any IP addresses matching your `$mynetworks` and
- `permit_sasl_authenticated` for permitting requests for ([RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954)) authenticated users.

*Sender Policy Framework* ([SPF](http://www.openspf.org/)) would do the same and work even if you can't trust all the outgoing servers to be in `$mynetworks` or if they are hard to list as IP addresses (e.g. `include:spf.protection.outlook.com`). Your domain seems to have an SPF record already:

```
calendridel.fr. IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip6:2001:41d0:1:e7c2::1 -all"
```

Currently you don't utilize this for your incoming mail. See [How To Implement SPF In Postfix](https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_spf).

Remember, that all this only works if your domain is used for the *envelope sender* address. It's still possible to spoof the `From:` header to be anything. E.g. Spamassassin can handle such cases. However, the *envelope sender* and `From:` header mismatch isn't generally wrong. If any external service isn't used to send email on behalf of your domain, then you could create a rule for that. Luckily, most of the spam would get enough score for other reasons even without such a rule.

Comment: Yep, I did `postmap` it after any changes. Thx for the explanation about `check_sender_access`, I wasn't sure (but I was able to send e-mails since the change was made.. ^^ ).

I hope those actions will be enough, otherwise I'll try to create a rule as you said. Quick question, and I hope the answer is "yes" : am I the only one to receive those messages from my domain ? Meaning : nobody else is receiving those messages from "me", right ? ^^

Anyway, thx for your answer.

Comment: Someone could receive spoofed mail having your domain in the `From:` header, but your current SPF record should prevent using it as an _envelope sender_. Frankly, every decent email service provider today performs checks against SPF. A domain having such record isn't as favorable for spammers than one without.

Comment: So I was waiting a few hours to see if the last change was efficient. Turns out it is not :( . I receive a new e-mail... If I understand it well, if I configure postfix to use SPF for incoming mail, it will just filter the e-mails i am receiving, right ? It's good for me, but what about those guys using my domain to send e-mails ? How is it possible with the configuration I made ? It's a lot of questions ^^

Comment: You were talking about "creating a rule", would you have some explanations/a link about how to do it ? Thanks a lot for your concern.

Comment: FYI, i didn't receive anything for the past 2 days... I'm gonna cross fingers :)