# Postfix - External incoming mails with company domain

Tags: email, postfix, exchange, spam, phishing

We use postfix as internal and external relay and Exchange inside the organization. Our company is receiving a lot of SPAM and phising mails whose Sender is our own company domain.
Searching Exchange Message-trackingLog I realized that altough the Sender is "ourdomain.com" the Return path is another.

Sender                  : userx@ourdomain.net
ReturnPath              : astrid.montoya@gmaritimo.com

I would like to configure in Postfix so that incoming emails that have our domain are blocked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MrShunz I have a problem with your linked question. That question explicitly asks not to use SPF or DKIM. But properly configuring SPF and/or DKIM is the proper solution.

Comment: @kasperd I agree... flag retracted.

Comment: It is suggested that implementing SPF for your domain and testing sender SPF in Postfix.     https://serverfault.com/questions/905591/receiving-spam-from-my-own-email-address-postfix

Comment: After you have set up SPF and DKIM, then I would also look at setting up DMARC https://dmarc.org/overview/